# with limit(20) it runs only the first 20 values of DB

Tags: 7, database

In this lines of code it selects only the first 0-20 but i want the first time select the first 0-20 and then the other(20-40) and other(40-60) and so on. How I can solve this problem?

```
 function something_cron()
      $query = db_select('watchdog', 'wa')
        ->extend('PagerDefault')
        ->orderBy('wid')
        ->fields('wa', array('variables', 'type', 'severity',
      'message', 'wid', 'timestamp'))
        ->limit(20);
      $result = $query->execute();

      // Loop through each item and add to $row.
      foreach ($result as $row) {
        someother();
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common pattern is to store the last ID processed in a variable, using variable_set(). Then you can retrieve it using variable_get() with a default of 0 before running your query, and add a condition to the query for wid being greater:

```
$last_id = variable_get('mymodule_last_id', 0);
...
->condition('wid', $last_id, '>')

...
$last_id = value from row
variable_set('mymodule_last_id', $last_id);
```

Comment: Finally!!! Thank you so much it was not so difficult as i supposed :D thank you so much my friend!

Comment: could you help me out with this also? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/152037/join-a-select-form-with-the-number-of-the-database-to-check