# Join a select form with the number of the database to check

Tags: forms

I have this select form:

```
$options = array(
      'twenty' => '20',
      'hundred' => '100',
      'five_hundred' => '500',
      'thousand' => '1.000',
      'five_thousand' => '5.000',
      'ten_thousand' => '10.000',
      'hudred_thousand' => '100.000',
      'million' => '1.000.000',
      'two-million' => '2.000.000',
  );

  $form['number_select'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $options,
    '#description' => t('Select the number of values that you want to check.'),
  );
```

I want according to what number the user has selected to limit the same number how i can solve this problem?

my DB code is this:

```
function something_cron()

  $number = variable_get(number_select)
  $query = db_select('watchdog', 'wa')
    ->orderBy('wid')
    ->fields('wa', array('variables', 'type', 'severity', 'message', 'wid',
    'timestamp'))
    ->condition('wid', $last_id, '>')
    ->range(0,$number);
  $result = $query->execute();

  // Loop through each item and add to $row.
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    someother();
  }
```

Comment: Where are you storing the result that they input? Also, how will the user know when you have performed the check, whatever it is? I assume they won't be expecting an immediate response.

Comment: it runs when cron runs and it has a save configuration button

Comment: I only want to let the user to select how many the value of limit will be

Comment: Do you mean the value used in `range(0,20)`? Letting them put a million in there may be dangerous.

Comment: ok but just tell me how to do this thing

Comment: Have you read this: https://www.drupal.org/node/206761?

Comment: I made some changes to my code by it still not working look my code now with $number... What I mut change in order to work this thing??

Comment: when i reload the page it keeps the value but i run it for 20 and all goes fine and then i change the value to 2000 and again i take the same values as when i have the number 20 selected.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Please don't change the code once you get an answer, or the given answer doesn't make sense anymore. Questions are not just for the benefit of the user who asks the question, but also future users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your options to this:

```
$options = array(
      '20' => '20',
      '100' => '100',
      '500' => '500',
      '1000' => '1.000',
...
  );
```

Then you can use the value directly. It'll be a number. Also you need a #default_value:

```
#default_value => variable_get('number_select', '20')
```

Comment: i did the changes you tell me but it only runs for 20 values

Comment: That suggests the number is not getting saved in the variable. Please carefully follow the instructions for a module configuration form I linked to above. Double check *everything*. If the value is saved correctly and your code is right, then when you reload the page the value you selected previously should still appear as the current selection.